# Guide for versioning an android application

Tags: android

I am trying to release an update of an existing Android application.

What is the correct way of versioning an Android application?

Here [Developer guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html) I found that format may be `<major>.<minor>.<point>`.

Can someone please explain me what each of `major`, `minor` and `point` mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`androidVersionCode` is an integer that you increase with each update. So the first version could be 1, the next update could be 2, etc.

`androidVersionName` is just a string value that you decide - it's displayed on Google Play.

The documentation refers to `<major>.<minor>.<point>` as a suggested format for the versionName, e.g. version 1.1.1 or 2.0.4. It's up to you, but there's a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826580/what-rules-does-software-version-numbering-follow).

Comment: You would increase <point> if your update included a bug fix or something simple. It would imply that no major features have changed in that update, yet it is still a newer version, hence an increased version number.

Comment: Thank you :) This is what i was expecting for :) sorry for asking again about <point> because i didn't see the link you had given :)

Answer (score 2):

As long as you update `android:versionCode` each time, it doesn't really matter what you put into `android:versionName`. It can be three different numbers or any other string, e.g. "1.0.0", "a", or "best release ever".

This is a general discussion of [Software Versioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning) from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:

- MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
- MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
- PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

I wrote a post about versioning android apps: https://blog.dipien.com/versioning-android-apps-d6ec171cfd82

Answer (score 1):

The version code is an integer and must be strictly increasing with each new version.

The version name is totally up to you. A scheme that is often used is x.y where x is incremented for really big changes (maybe even introducing incompatibilities with previous versions), while y is incremented for minor changes.